# Excel combining up to 100 ranges that have similar but not identical columns into one

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pulling in data for unique items and each item has a potentially unique set of columns that go with it. So for instance as a trivial example two ranges might look this:

Range 1:

```
Brand   Year  MPG   Sales
Nissan  2000  25    150
Nissan  2005  27    180
Nissan  2008  30    190
```

Range2:

```
Brand   Year    Sales
Honda   2000    95
Honda   2001    100
Honda   2001    150
```

Ideally I would like to combine into one named range:

```
Brand   Year    MPG Sales
Nissan  2000    25  150
Nissan  2005    27  180
Nissan  2008    30  190
Honda   2000    Null    95
Honda   2001    Null    100
Honda   2001    Null    150
```

In reality I have something like 100+ named ranges like this and the columns vary from anywhere between 25-35.

Is there a smart way to achieve the desired result? I'm trying right now to use vba to loop through each range and check if the row exists, but that seems like kind of a sloppy solution and I'm having issues getting it to work, but I can probably brute force it through.

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Once you've decided where the final results will go, you can use Match() to locate the corresponding header for each column in each range you're consolidating: if you get a match then copy the data there, - if there's no match then add the header and then copy the data.

Comment: @TimWilliams do you mean if I set them as a table so I can access the headers? Can you access headers of a named range if it's not as a table? I can set them as a table I suppose, I just started in VBA as a named range. The other issue is that match function would have to reference different ranges at different points in the table, so the first 40 rows might reference one range using a combo of index/match, but the the next 40 might have to reference a different range entirely, I'm not sure how to make this process smoother

Comment: @SJR I can post a trimmed down version of my sloppy code, but its just a for loop where it looks for each name in the first row of the first range and checks other ranges for a match in the column header and then pastes the data if there's a match. I've gotten it to work on a simplified example but it fails at a larger scale I'm not sure why. I'm mostly just looking for a suggestion and if there's a feature in excel that I'm not aware of. The raw coding work I'm sure I can handle, Im just not sure if there's a smarter way than dumb brute force looping

Comment: `Range("nameHere").Rows(1)` will be the headers. You don't need tables for this.

Comment: You can do this with Power Query and just append all the tables.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware about Power Query, seems like a new function, it's not in my excel but I'm looking into getting it as an add on. Can I ask if you can use power query in a quick way? Will I have to manually add 100 tables with clicks or can it be automated to be done in a reasonably quick way?

Comment: @TimWilliams for some reason when I try this I get an invalid use of property. I pasted my code trying your method in my OP, unless you meant to do it in excel itself? In which case I don't see a Range function.

Comment: @TimWilliams nvm, I'm an idiot, I never assigned it to a variable so I kept getting a property use error. I see now what you mean, I can assign the rows to a variable. As a question is it possible to paste this variable which exists in VBA into excel itself? So for instance if I variable Rows which has the first row of one of my ranges, can I paste it? It's unclear to me how

Comment: Yes, if it's not present in your Excel and you have 2010+, MS has a free add-in. In 2016+ it's called `Get & Transform`.  And you could manually add 100 tables with clicks, or with manually editing the M-Code.  You can also create the M-code using VBA (which might be the fastest way to do this with 100 tables).  Once you've developed the code, if any tables are modified, all you need to do is refresh the query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Pardon my ignorance, but what is M-Code? I'll look into using VBA to use powerquery, I wasn't sure if that was doable but some googling indicates it might be

Comment: MCode is the code underlying Power Query.  See [Power Query M formula language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you so much. Love this site, got like 2 or 3 suggestions I didn't even know existed, hopefully I have enough to do it slightly better from here